# Error appending data to existing PostgreSQL database for OSM with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

When running osm2psql on an existing database I get an error

`osm2pgsql -v -d gis -a -s -G --flat-nodes ./nodes.cache --number-processes 8 ./thailand.osm.pbf`

Output is :

```
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=12800*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: loading persistent node cache from ./nodes.cache
Mid: pgsql, cache=800
SQL command failed: ERROR:  relation "planet_osm_ways" does not exist
LINE 1: ...REPARE mark_ways_by_node(int8) AS  SELECT id FROM planet_osm...
                                                             ^

Full query: PREPARE mark_ways_by_node(int8) AS  SELECT id FROM planet_osm_ways    WHERE nodes && ARRAY[$1];
PREPARE mark_ways_by_rel(int8) AS  SELECT id FROM planet_osm_ways    WHERE id IN (      SELECT unnest(parts[way_off+1:rel_off])        FROM planet_osm_rels WHERE id = $1    );

node cache: stored: 0(0.00%), storage efficiency: 0.00% (dense blocks: 0, sparse nodes: 0), hit rate: 0.00%
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Executing SQL
```

Displaying current existing tables in postgres gives:

```
gis=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+--------------------+-------+-------
 public | planet_osm_line    | table | osm
 public | planet_osm_point   | table | osm
 public | planet_osm_polygon | table | osm
 public | planet_osm_roads   | table | osm
 public | spatial_ref_sys    | table | osm
(5 rows)
```

As I understand it, the -s option (slim mode) is supposed to create 3 new tables : https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/pgsql.md#database-layout

```
planet_osm_nodes
planet_osm_ways
planet_osm_rels
```

It's like osm2psql tries to access those tables before creating them at first.

PS: I also tried without the flat-nodes option
`osm2pgsql -v -d gis -a -s -G -C 40000 --number-processes 8 ./thailand.osm.pbf` with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

First, to be able to `append` new data, you must have **initially** loaded the 1st dataset using the `slim` option.

Then you can't append an entire dataset, but only the `diff` file, that you either download (like the daily diff) or create.

Comment: All right, this is really unclear in the documentation. Is there a way to append a new dataset then ? I'm guessing the solution is to create my own diff file : `osmconvert old.osm new.osm --diff -o=changefile.osc` but will that work anyway if I didn't created with the `slim` option at first ?

Comment: Yes, computing the difference and applying it is the option for appending data. No, it won't work if you didn't use `slim` the 1st time. It may be faster/easier to just replace the dataset instead of updating it